# Problems with array_merge

Tags: php, arrays, merge, yii2

I have two models each returning an array (provided by the ERP system). Now I want to merge these arrays and all I have the parameters and values ​​in one array.

The problem is that the $new array is empty. The 'Parameters' was an string (e.g. 'cost_all'), an die 'Value' is an float or an string.

```
$new =  [];
$arrayFloat = ArrayHelper::map(ParameterFloat::findAll($this->id), 'Parameter', 'Value');        
$arrayString = ArrayHelper::map(ParameterString::findAll($this->id), 'Parameter', 'Value');

$new = array_merge($arrayFloat, $arrayString);
```

```php
$arrayFloat = 
array(681) (
  [005001000000nr_rrr_idnr] => (float) -1
  [005001000000nr_rrr_kdnr] => (float) -1
  [005001000000nr_rrra_kdnr] => (float) -1
  [005001000000nr_rrrb_kdnr] => (float) -1

...

$arrayString = 
array(436) (
  [005001000000algos] => (string) none
  [005002000000algos] => (string) none
  [005003000000algos] => (string)
  [005004000000algos] => (string) lx325
  [006580000000algos] => (string) lx345

...
```

Comment: What does $arrayFloat and $arrayString contain ? try dumping them before merging

Comment: Provide a sample of both the arrays, as mentioned in above comment

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($arrayFloat, $arrayString);` and see if those values are arrays.

Comment: See an example in the question above. By the way: Can I post a code in a comment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
$arrayFloat = json_decode(json_encode($arrayFloat),true); // flushes any object dependancies to perform array operations
$arrayString = json_decode(json_encode($arrayString),true);

$new = array_merge($arrayFloat, $arrayString);
print_r($new);
```

Comment: how to get value of what?